# Can Wix ProgId set the working directory?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have the following snippet in my wix file. I need the working directory to be set, but it doesn't appear the ProgId supports this. The Shortcut element has a WorkingDirectory attribute, but it appears that ProgId doesn't support it. Is there another way to set the working directory?

```
  <Component>
    <File Source="program.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <ProgId Id="Program" Description="Program" Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes">
      <Extension Id="myfile" Advertise="yes">
        <Verb Id="open" Command="&amp;Open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" Sequence="1" />
      </Extension>
    </ProgId>
  </Component>
```

Comment: COM servers must be hosted by a client. It's the client (EXE) that creates/owns the process and sets the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because Windows Installer doesn't support it. Nor does Windows -- the handler must support running from any directory.